# In 霸王别姬 is 霸 just a name?

Tags: meaning

I have not seen the film or read the book， I can't judge.

Is this 霸 just a name, or does 霸王 really mean 'the tyrant king'？

Answer (score 3):

It can be a [general term](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E9%9C%B8%E7%8E%8B), i.e. not a proper name, but it is/was often used to refer to a certain historic person called [Xiang Yu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiang_Yu). So 霸王 will not translate as "King Ba".

Chinese Wikipedia:

> 霸王是指比一般王还强盛的君王，时常是文人雅士对项羽的尊称。

---

More references:

Baidu Baike:  [霸王](http://baike.baidu.com/subview/72575/5122187.htm)（汉语词语）

> 霸王，古时指霸和王，也用来尊称霸主，特指西楚霸王项羽，或者比喻非常蛮横的人。

In addition Baidu Baike lists [12 entries](http://baike.baidu.com/view/72575.htm?force=1) in total for this word.

Answer (score 3):

霸王 is used as a name for [Xiang Yu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiang_Yu), a famous warlord of the late [Qin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty) era, and this play is a straight-up usage of this name - it describes Xiang Yu bidding his concubine farewell. Other usages of the word "霸王" is usually in reference to him; for example [Sun Ce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Ce) and [Zhou Tong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhou_Tong_(Water_Margin)) both have the nickname of "小霸王" due to their martial prowess.

However, the character 霸 in 霸王 is not a name; it simply takes its [actual meaning of "hegemony" or "tyranny"](http://www.zdic.net/z/27/js/9738.htm). Thus 霸王 is translated as "hegemon-king", "king-of-kings" and so on. It describes a king that, unlike normal kings, has dominion over other kings without being an emperor. This is exactly what Xiang Yu was when he claimed the title 西楚霸王.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation (霸王别姬), 霸王 usually means a king who is stronger than other kings.

Comment: 霸王 usually means "overlord", but **in this situation**, 霸王 means 西楚霸王 (i.e. 项羽), and 姬 means 虞姬 (the wife of 西楚霸王). Haven't you heard the story of 霸王别姬 ? It's so famous.